# Input in sweetalert 2 not typeable in material UI modal react js

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a card to display an order and inside the card on cancellation sweetalert2 popup opens asking for cancellation reason. This is working just fine on orders screen.
[image]

```
<Grid item md={8} sm={12}>
    orders.map((order) => <SupplierOrderBlock data={order} />)
</Grid>
```

And on Cancellation these swal fire. First one to ask the user to enter reason and if user doesnt enter a reason the second sweetalert to prompt user to enter a reason in order to cancel.

```
const cancelOrder = (orderID, status) => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are You Sure You Want to Cancel Order",
      text: "Please Enter the reason for the cancellation of order",
      input: "text",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#1c8fec",
      cancelButtonColor: "#fa013b",
      customClass: 'swal-wide'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value == '') {
        swal({
          title: "You can not cancel without giving a reason",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#1c8fec",
          cancelButtonColor: "#fa013b",
          buttons: {
            Confirm: { text: "Okay", className: "okayButton" },
          },
        });
      }
else if (result.isConfirmed) { //cancel order}
```

This is working just fine.

Now when i try to use this same component on my dashboard inside a Material UI modal it doesnt let me enter text.

```
<Modal
        open={modal}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
        style={{ width: "60%", zIndex: 1, marginLeft: '-10%' }}
      >
        <Box style={{ marginLeft: "50%", marginTop: "25vh", width: "100%", position: 'absolute' }}>
          <SupplierOrderBlock data={supplierorder} />
        </Box>
      </Modal>
```

[image]

If i remove Z-index property from Modal then swal goes behind the modal
[image]

But on closing the modal it lets us enter reason
[image]

Comment: I am applying z-index to the modal, thoough I ma getting sweet alert behind the mui modal. Any idea how to solve it? I mean how to show it above modal?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered untypeable input issue with SweetAlert2 within a Material-UI Dawer in React? Here's a fix:

The problem lies in MUI Drawer/Modal Focus management. To resolve, use the disableEnforceFocus property to drawer/modal. When set to true, it lets the drawer lose focus, making input possible.

However, note this might affect accessibility for screen readers. Proceed thoughtfully.

here is the code snippet -

```html
<Drawer id="drawer" anchor="right" open={true} **disableEnforceFocus**
}}>
    {
    <MyComponent/>//Inside this component i have sweetalert
    }
</Drawer>
```

I hope same property will resolve issue in case of MUI Modal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).